# After creating an NSTextField with editable area, not able to type anything

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, nstextfield

I can't seem to get this working, which is a bit interesting to say the least.

So, I have a couple friends and we have an example set of code we're supposed to use and expand upon for a project. The problem? It only appears to work properly on Windows-based machines. The entire project is a java to objective c server/client relationship. We previously did Java to Java, and are now having to get the Objective C portion working.

The code is here(Please note, this is just a very small snippet of the code in comparison to the whole project):

```
- (NSTextField*) addFieldWithTitle:(NSString*) aTitle at: (NSRect) aRect {
NSTextField* label =[[[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame: aRect] autorelease];
[label setSelectable: YES];
[label setEditable: YES];
[label setBezeled: YES];
[label setDrawsBackground: YES];
[label setStringValue: aTitle];
[[window contentView] addSubview: label];
return label;
}
```

On my Mac it shows up properly, and allows each field to be selected (each field that NEEDS to be selected, that is). But the problem is as follows: After selecting the field, you cannot type anything. Whatever is typed is then received by the previous program / application you had open just prior to selecting this "program" that shows up. It appears to not register it properly at all, because it doesn't type at all.

What makes it even more interesting is that I can right click (or control click) the editable fields, and then select "paste" and it will paste the strings that I had previously copied to the clip board...

So that's my interesting issue, and I can't seem to find any answers and my classmates cannot find answers either.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Regards,
Michael

P.S. If you would like the full code we are running, I can provide that as well.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you posted -- I pasted it into a project, and it worked fine. The problem has to be elsewhere.

Comment: The entirety of the code is listed here: http://pooh.poly.asu.edu/Cst420/Assigns/Assign3/sampleAssign3.jar
So I don't really know what's going on, but it appears to be mac-specific..

Comment: Better yet, here is a video outlining EXACTLY what is happening. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pn1QFOa44IA&feature=youtu.be

Comment: I would also like to add that I am running 10.8.2, if that might have an affect on my issue.